# How can I change data set features during each boosting iteration in xgboost?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, xgboost

I am trying to replicate the algorithm in this paper - https://www.ii.pwr.edu.pl/~tomczak/PDF/[MZSTJT].pdf

The way I understand it I need to:

1. Train a base learner with an initial data set.
2. From the trained model take the importance of features and get rid of the unimportant ones via a threshold(for example at least 5% of all splits).
3. From the rest make a simple probability distribution based on their f-score(number of splits).
4. Using this distribution sample two features with replacement and do a random mathematical operation(+,-,*,/) between them(example: f1*f2).Do this a few times.
5. Add the resulting new features to the new data set.
6. Train the next base learner with the new data set consisting of the most important features from the last iteration plus the newly generated ones.

I am using the Python API of xgboost. Is there a way to control the Dmatrix in between iterations, so I can add the new features?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware this is not possible out of the box. The problem is that each tree of the ensemble would have different features, which the algorithm is not made for (to my best knowledge).

What you could do instead is train a model with your Dmatrix, do your feature selection/ generation and create a new Dmatrix including the new features and train a new boosted tree model.

Just glancing over the paper I'd say what they propose is mostly what I suggested above. They do not include the new features for previous base learners and basically the learner can be any model (it's probably just that gradient boosted trees did perform exceptionally well in recent times - aside from CNNs). The result of their algorithm is just a set of "base" models. They call it an ensemble of boosted trees (so an ensemble of an ensemble).

Their method is mostly a wrapper variant of ordinary feature selection procedures with the special part that they create synthetic features in addition.

On a side note, their results don't really look that good, sure it's significant but what isn't given enough data. You can just as well use the original XGBoost algorithm and will most likely not end up worse in terms of real world performance (just my two cents).